# Debug PostgreSQL lock count with check_postgres.pl

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

We use check_postgres.pl to monitor our database.

We use this to check the count of the locks:

https://bucardo.org/check_postgres/check_postgres.pl.html#locks

We often see more than 150 locks.

The question was: What is going on? We patched the script to output this sql statement, if the lock count was exceeded:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity order by datname
```

Unfortunately the result is not what I was expecting. Although there are more than 150 locks, pg_stat_activity shows only few (less then 10) queries.

This has happened about twice a day during the last days, and every time only few lines where returned by pg_stat_activity.

What is going on here?

How to debug the current DB state if there are too many locks?

Comment: A single DML statement can easily obtain millions of locks. There is no relation to the number of statements and the number of locks. But why are 150 locks a bad thing? Unless they are held for a long time (minutes, hours) I don't see any reason to check this. Also: `pg_stat_activity` doesn't show "queries", it shows open connections. That is something completely different.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok you see no reason to monitor the number of short living locks. What is your general advice: don't monitor locks at all, or monitor them but different. Then the question is: how to monitor them?

Comment: Just for the records, I asked on the mailing list roughly the same question: https://mail.endcrypt.com/pipermail/check_postgres/2015-December/001085.html

Comment: The only monitoring that would make sense to me is the _duration_ of the locks (e.g. locks held for more than 5 minutes). Or the number of transactions _waiting_ for a lock.

Comment: I created a different question which asks "How can I check for the lock count and ignore all locks which are only N seconds old?" http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124213/check-lock-count-for-postgresql The above question is still valid: How to debug the current DB state if there are too many locks?