# Check lock count for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

Up to now we used check_postgres.pl to monitor our database.

We used this to check the count of the locks:

https://bucardo.org/check_postgres/check_postgres.pl.html#locks

We often see more than 150 locks.

I was told this in a different question: [How to Debug check_postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123945/checking-postgresql-lock-count-with-check-postgres-pl)

> A single DML statement can easily obtain millions of locks. There is no 
>   relation to the number of statements and the number of locks. But why are 
>   150 locks a bad thing? Unless they are held for a long time (minutes, 
>   hours) I don't see any reason to check this.

How can I check for the lock count and ignore all locks which are only N seconds old?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I check for the lock count and ignore all locks which are only N seconds old?

You can't... but I think you're asking the wrong question.

PostgreSQL has many different kinds of locking. The three main ones visible to users are:

- Row locks
- Heavyweight locks
- Advisory locks

A row lock is a lock taken by `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, `SELECT ... FOR SHARE`, etc, indicating a claim on a row. You cannot see these in the `pg_locks` view and they don't consume resources. This is what *"a single DML statement can easily obtain millions of locks"* refers to.

Heavyweight locks are what people usually mean when they say "lock" without qualifying with the lock type. They're seen in `pg_locks`. There are many kinds: locks on relations (tables, views, etc); locks to allow one transaction to wait on another, etc. They're only "heavyweight" compared to PostgreSQL's internal lightweight locking mechanism (LWLocks); you don't have to worry unless you start exceeding `max_locks_per_transaction`.

Advisory locks are a utility locking mechanism for applications. They're done with function calls. They're visible in `pg_locks`.